# What is this insect that showed up after I left food out? How can I get rid of it?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

These bugs showed up after I left some food out. I noticed a significant reduction after I cleaned up my place, but now they're back again. They're pretty small, but can you guys help me identify these bugs. I need to look up how to get rid of them.

I live in the Midwest.

I realize the quality is not the best.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of food was it?

Comment: It looks like it could be some type of fruit fly.  Without clearer pictures it would be difficult to say what kind.

Comment: I don't recall, it was a long time ago. It seems to like my trash can very much.

Comment: @Kurt Uploaded a clearer pic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely a fruit fly, a *Drosophila melanogaster*.

[image]

I've tried different methods to trap then but the most effective way I found is [this](https://lifehacker.com/5604246/make-an-effective-fruit-fly-trap-with-no-tools-or-cutting). You need a container (pan, jar, bowl, whatever), vinegar (I use any type), a drop of dish soap, and plastic wrap over the top with holes poked in. Then the flies cannot stand on top of the liquid but also have issues escaping through the holes in the plastic wrap.

Answer (score 2):

If it looks like the picture below it is some sort of fruit fly.  I've also attached a [link](http://www.infobarrel.com/Fruit_Flies_in_House_-_3_Ways_to_Get_Them_Out_Fast) telling how to get rid of them.

[image]